# Search for matches in DataList using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

First, I'm working in C#, in ASP.NET, I have a DataList with employees, and the names are in Labels, into a ItemTemplate.

Then I need a JavaSript funtion that catch the text typed by the user and compare it with the Label's text. If exits a coincidence show the Row, else hide it.

```html
<asp:DataList ID="dt_usuario" runat="server" CellPadding="4" OnItemCommand="dt_usuario_ItemCommand"
                    ForeColor="#333333" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1px" ItemStyle-BorderColor="Gray" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Dashed" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1px">
                    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id_usuario" )%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:450px;" title="emploee">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nom_institucion") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lkreport" runat="server" Text="Reporte" CommandName="Reporte" class="btn btn-7 btn-7ba icon-reporte"><span><center>Imprimir</center></span></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
```

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSeach" Width="400px" onkeyup="javascript:Seach(this)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I'm tried to create my own funtion, but didn't work

```js
function Seach(phrase)
        {
            var palabra = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
            var datalist = document.getElementById('<%=dt_usuario.ClientID%>');
            for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++)
            {
                var usuario = datalist.rows[i].getElementById("lblUsuario").value;
                var institucion = datalist.rows[i].getElementById("lblInstitucion").value;
                if (usuario.match(/palabra.*/) || institucion.match(/palabra.*/))
                {
                    datalist.rows[i].visible = false;
                }
            }
            
        }
    </script>
```

I hope somebody could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few adjustements that you can make to your code:

1. Since the table rows don't support the `getElementById` method, the `getElementsByClassName` method can be used instead. A common class name can be given to the Labels targeted by the search, so that they can be retrieved with a single call.
2. The Labels being rendered as `span` elements, their content is given by the `innerHTML` property instead of `value`.
3. The `display` style can be used to show/hide the rows, instead of the `visible` property (which does not exist).
4. You refer to Labels with IDs `lblUsuario` and `lblInstitucion` in your function but I don't see them in your markup. I assume that they were lost when you copied/pasted your code in the question.

**Typical markup for the Labels in the DataList:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblUsuario" runat="server" CssClass="fieldValue" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nom_usuario") %>' />
<asp:Label ID="lblInstitucion" runat="server" CssClass="fieldValue" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nom_institucion") %>' />
```

**The Search function:**

```
function Search(phrase) {
    var i, j, k;
    var fields, foundMatch;
    var palabra = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    var datalist = document.getElementById('<%= dt_usuario.ClientID %>');
    for (i = 0; i < datalist.rows.length; i++) {
        foundMatch = false;
        fields = datalist.rows[i].getElementsByClassName('fieldValue');
        for (j = 0; j < palabra.length; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < fields.length; k++) {
                if (fields[k].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(palabra[j]) >= 0) {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        datalist.rows[i].style.display = foundMatch ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are after. You can use [`RegEx.IsMatch(input, pattern)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx)

First, add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Then:

```
function Seach(phrase)
    {
        var word = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var datalist = document.getElementById('<%=dt_employee.ClientID%>');
        for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++)
        {
            var empl = datalist.rows[i].getElementById("lblemployee").value;
            if (RegEx.IsMatch(empl, word))
            {
                datalist.rows[i].visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: But this works just in the codebehind, or it works that in the html in a script?

Comment: This is codebehind. I don't know javascript, and also am a bit unsure of what you are trying to do. I assume you are having a problem with this line: `if (empl.match(/word.*/))`, so I tried to fix that line..

Comment: I did the correction and use `RegEx`, but i write in the TextBox and the DataList doesn't change

Comment: Try with `if (RegEx.IsMatch(empl, word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))`